# How can I add the form using channels?

Tags: channel-entries, safecracker

How can I add the multi-step forms using channels and uploading the data to database?
And then perform searching on the same data.
Also please suggest me that how booking process works for expression-engine ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly suggest you look at purchasing [Solspace Freeform Pro](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/) which can do something very similar but will be far easier to implement. It can handle multi-page forms, it stores the data to the database and has tags to retrieve. As an alternative there is also [DevDemon Forms](http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/forms) covering much the same thing.

Your second question: "Also please suggest me that how booking process works for expression-engine" - is too far ranging to be able to answer. There is no booking process in ExpressionEngine, EE is so flexible you can do whatever you need - it's a blank canvas. Your best approach would be to ask a new question providing much more specific detail on your requirements if you want to get a specific answer. If you want people to spend time and effort helping you with an answer, put some effort into the question.